# How to use Google Protobuf Map in C++?

Tags: c++, hashmap, protocol-buffers, c++14

I am attempting to use the new protobuf Map functionality in C++.

The following was done on Ubuntu 14.04 with gcc 4.9.2 C++14 and protobuf 3.0.0-alpha-4:

Message definition:

```
message TestMap {
     map<string,uint64> map1 = 1;
}
```

Then, I tried to compile the following example program:

```
auto test = debug::TestMap::default_instance();
auto map = test.mutable_map1();
string key = "key";
uint64 val = 20;
map[key] = val;
```

Acccessing the map using the [] syntax works totally fine for std::unordered_map. But the protobuf implementation always yields the following compiler error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘google::protobuf::Map<std::basic_string<char>, long unsigned int>*’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
```

I do not understand why this operator is not known, because the header file *google::protobuf::Map* is clearly found and this should be an elementary operation.

Do you have any idea what goes wrong here? I would welcome any example of using the new protobuf maps, as I haven't found any online after researching for hours.

Comment: Your `map` variable seems to be a pointer. Did you try `*map[key]`?

Comment: @Pixelchemist: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. `*map[key]` does not work, but  `*(map)[key]` does. Quite a basic one! I have looked in the wrong direction all along.

Comment: @Pixelchemist: Do you want to post the answer or should I do it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As *Pixelchemist* pointed out, the problem is that `map` is a pointer so the `[]` operator does not work.

Thus, the pointer needs to be dereferenced first. `*map[key]` also does not work, as the compiler first parses `[]` and then the `*`. The following does work:

```
(*map)[key] = val;
```

Although this is a quite basic problem, this represents a good learning opportunity for C++ and Protocol Buffers.

Comment: FWIW, you could do: `auto& map = *test.mutable_map1();`, and then `map[key]` would work.

Comment: Thanks Kenton! That is much more reable and easier to maintain.

Comment: map->operator[](key) = val;

Comment: is mutable_map the only method to use to access the map?

Comment: @ChristopherPisz No. `test.map1()` gives you a `const` reference, if you only need acess instead of modification. Doc is here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated